# Is it possible to use python 2.7 with julia while anaconda is preinstalled with python 3.4?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, opencv, julia, anaconda

I installed julia and am using some nice python packages like matplotlib in julia using PyCall. I have installed all python stuff with anaconda and used python 3.4. I am able to switch from enviroment in anaconda to use python 2.7.

The thing is that I would like to import openCV as a python package in julia but it only runs with python 2.7. So I was wondering if it was possible to use python 2.7 in julia trough anaconda while python 3.4 was in anaconda's main install.

A working option would be to reinstall anaconda with version 2.7, but I don't want that.

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: For the people who come here because @pyimport opencv did not work using PyCall, "As a workaround, you can just do cv = pyimport("cv2") and access cv.foo with cv[:foo]"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Current Anaconda installation

### OpenCV3 on Python3

> The thing is that I would like to import openCV as a python package in julia but it only runs with python 2.7.

Have you tried installing OpenCV3 with your Anaconda Python version 3.x installation?

- [`conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3`](https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3)

### Add another Python 2.7 environment

You could also create new Anaconda Python environment with Python 2.7 installed using your current Anaconda install with `conda create`:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda
```

Assuming you are using the full Anaconda distribution, I understand this will install a **full** Anaconda Python 2.7 environment (see `miniconda`, below), but it will not mess up your previous Anaconda Python 3 env.

- http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html#install-a-different-version-of-python

## Conda.jl Julia package

You could use [`Conda.jl`](https://github.com/Luthaf/Conda.jl) for managing Julia binary dependencies:

> This package allows one to use `conda` as a binary provider for Julia. While other binary providers like `Hombrew.jl`, `AptGet.jl` or `WinRPM.jl` are platform-specific, `Conda.jl` is a cross-platform alternative. It can also be used without administrator rights, in contrast to the current Linux-based providers.
>
> `conda` is a package manager which started as the binary package manager for the Anaconda Python distribution, but it also provides arbitrary packages. **Instead of the full Anaconda distribution, `Conda.jl` uses the *miniconda* Python environment, which only includes `conda` and its dependencies.**
>
> You can install it by running `Pkg.add("Conda")` at the Julia prompt.

### Install and load `Conda.jl`:

```
julia> # Pkg.add("Conda")

julia> using Conda
```

### Search for the package:

```
julia> Conda.search("opencv")
1-element Array{AbstractString,1}:
 "opencv"
```

### Install the package:

```
julia> Conda.add("opencv")
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: ....................
Package plan for installation in environment /home/ismaelvc/.julia/v0.4/Conda/deps/usr:

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    jpeg-8d                    |                0         699 KB
    wheel-0.29.0               |           py27_0          81 KB
    opencv-2.4.10              |      np110py27_1         9.2 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        10.0 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    jpeg:   8d-0              
    opencv: 2.4.10-np110py27_1

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    wheel:  0.26.0-py27_1 --> 0.29.0-py27_0

Fetching packages ...
jpeg-8d-0.tar. 100% |##########| Time: 0:00:01 652.02 kB/s
wheel-0.29.0-p 100% |##########| Time: 0:00:00 336.94 kB/s
opencv-2.4.10- 100% |##########| Time: 0:00:10 962.48 kB/s
Extracting packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##########| 100%
Unlinking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##########| 100%
Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##########| 100%
```

> **Total:        10.0 MB**

### Check that it worked:

```
shell> .julia/v0.4/Conda/deps/usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.11 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'2.4.10'
>>>
```

#### Within Julia via `PyCall`:

```
julia> using PyCall    # Pkg.add("PyCall")

julia> @pyimport cv2

julia> @pyimport sys

julia> sys.version |> println
2.7.11 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]

julia> import Conda

julia> Conda.PYTHONDIR
"/home/ismaelvc/.julia/v0.4/Conda/deps/usr/bin"
```

### Specify the python version for PyCall

- https://github.com/stevengj/PyCall.jl#specifying-the-python-version

## Miniconda

Or use `miniconda` for Python 2.7 directly:

- http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html

`Conda.jl` installs by default the Python version 2.7.x `miniconda` (installing everything in `~/.julia/v0.x/Conda`).

## In Linux:

It is often very easy to install only the things you want, without having to use Anaconda (I'm assuming you use Mac or PC, but still useful to others), example uses **ArchLinux** package manager `pacman`, it's similar with other Linux distributions package managers like: `yum`, `zipper`, `apt-get`, etc:

```
shell> sudo pacman -S opencv
warning: opencv-2.4.12.2-2 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Package (1)   Old Version  New Version  Net Change  Download Size

extra/opencv  2.4.12.2-2   2.4.12.2-2     0.00 MiB       7.10 MiB

Total Download Size:    7.10 MiB
Total Installed Size:  38.86 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:       0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] n

shell> python2
Python 2.7.11 (default, Dec  6 2015, 15:43:46)
[GCC 5.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'2.4.12.2'
>>>
```

Comment: That is pretty small indeed, but is it also possible for conda to switch python versions? Btw, I was wondering if with your install you are able to import opencv in julia? I ran into some trouble when doing so. Other python packages did work but @pyimport cv2 gave errors, so I am considering your build. I am actually testing the possibilities for image processing with julia.

Comment: @F.Wessels yes, I am able to do `@pyimport cv2`, I have updated the answer, you can also use `conda create` to create new environments which may have different python versions installed: http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html#install-a-different-version-of-python

Comment: Conda.jl is unzipped to /opt/julia/julia-1.1.0/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Conda. What is the correct path to install Miniconda3-4.6.14-Linux-x86_64.sh? Whether it is /opt/julia/julia-1.1.0/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Conda/deps/usr/bin/conda or some where else?

Comment: @AVA how are you installing `Conda.jl`? Did you do `add Conda` at thi Julia package prompt?

Comment: Just unzipped Conda.jl.

Comment: @AVA  Do you have some kind of network restriction? Why are you trying to install it that way? Just open the Julia REPL, type `]` the prompt will change to `pkg> ` and then type `add Conda`. This will clone and build Conda for you in the appropriate place, see: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Pkg/index.html